# VBA - Copy cell and paste into an empty cell on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I'm new to VBA so please bear with me. 
I was wondering if someone could help me please with an issue I am experiencing.
Can someone help me copy the cell V10 in a sheet named "Standard_NewSale_GSS" and paste into the next available empty cell in the Column E in the "Standard_Basket" sheet. 
If anyone can help it would be very much appreciated! It's for my coursework at college.

Comment: and what did you do so far? Show us your work.

Comment: I havent really done any yet, I've been too afraid incase I make a mistake and mess everything up. @Tymoteusz Paul

Comment: Originally I tried this, I found it online somewhere and I've been trying to alter it to my requirements but there was an error unfortunately. Sub gss_addtobasket2()
'
' gss_addtobasket2 Macro

'
    Worksheets("Sheet9").Active
    Worksheets("Sheet9").Range("V10").Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet11").Active
    eRow = Sheet11.Cells(Row.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet11").Rows(eRow)
  
    
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to hardcode these values into your subroutine, you could do something like the following:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyIntoStandardBasketColumnE()
    Dim nextCellInColumn As Range
    Set nextCellInColumn = Worksheets("Standard_Basket").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    nextCellInColumn.Value = Worksheets("Standard_NewSale_GSS").Range("V10").Value
End Sub
```

This finds the last cell of column `E` in `Worksheets("Standard_Basket")` by starting at the last row of the worksheet and using `End(xlUp)` to find a cell with a value. Then it uses `Offset` to move to the next row. Finally it sets this cell's value to be equal to cell `V10` of `Worksheets("Standard_NewSales_GSS")`.

Comment: @KatieM: No problem. To easily allow other users of the website know that the solution worked for you, click the checkmark to the left of this answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow!